# Caching spatial queries

Tags: java, caching, gis, postgis

Given a service that returns some data for a location (lat/lng) querying an spatial database, I'm interested in a good way to use a memory caching strategy given that use cases:

- Lat/Long values will very difficult to be the same because are returned by mobile location providers
- Data returned by the service is in function of some fixed points -> Similar locations return the same values.
- I'm using Postgis/Java to do the job.

By now my best idea is to normalize the lat/lng using for example the first decimal. But not sure if there's a clever strategy or some gis support on that.

Comment: I don't know if its valid approach to write new code and use cache only to normalize the lat/lng. Can you give other example except lat/longt? Because Location listener based on GPS/network has sample frequency about 1-2sec

Answer (score 2):

So you want to use a Java Application as a caching layer to reduce the load on your spatial PostGIS database?

Yes a simple way would be to grid up the world, -180, -90 bottom right, to top left 180, 90 top right, and round the incoming lat/lon to the nearest degree/integer. Please round and not floor as it introduces a smaller error into the position.

Then store for the response for each new grid position as they come in.  I'd go for a 2D array.

A slightly more complex solution would be to use a smaller, double grid.

Answer (score 0):

Tarantool 1.6.4 has RTREE in-memory index, which could be used for nearest-neighbor and objects-within-a-rectangle search.
The index has been added specifically to be able to act as a fast in-memory cache for spatial queries against PostgreSQL.